# converting sql statement back to lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, lambda

I have the query below, and its sql code. It's running really slow, so it was re written in sql, now I'm just not sure how to convert the sql back to a lambda expression.

This is the part of the expression giving me the problems, somewhere in

> r.RecordProducts.Any()

```
                records = records
                .Include(r => r.Employer)
                .Include(r => r.Contractor)
                .Include(r => r.RecordProducts)
                .ThenInclude(rp => rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant)
                .Where(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Employer.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    || EF.Functions.Like(r.Contractor.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%") && rp.IsActive == true));
```

the any clause does an exist and some funky stuff in the sql where clause below

```html
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[StartDate], [t].[EndDate], [t].[WitnessName], [t].[SourceCode], [t].[JobsiteName], [t].[ShipName], [t].[EmployerCode]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [r].[RecordID] AS [Id], [r].[StartDate], [r].[EndDate], [r.Witness].[FullName] AS [WitnessName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[SourceID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Source].[SourceCode] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [SourceCode], CASE
        WHEN [r].[JobsiteID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteName] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [JobsiteName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[ShipID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Ship].[ShipName] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [ShipName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[EmployerID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Employer].[DefendantCode] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [EmployerCode]
    FROM [Records] AS [r]
    LEFT JOIN [Ships] AS [r.Ship] ON [r].[ShipID] = [r.Ship].[ShipID]
    LEFT JOIN [Jobsites] AS [r.Jobsite] ON [r].[JobsiteID] = [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteID]
    LEFT JOIN [Sources] AS [r.Source] ON [r].[SourceID] = [r.Source].[SourceID]
    LEFT JOIN [Witnesses] AS [r.Witness] ON [r].[WitnessID] = [r.Witness].[WitnessID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Contractor] ON [r].[ContractorID] = [r.Contractor].[DefendantID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Employer] ON [r].[EmployerID] = [r.Employer].[DefendantID]
    WHERE ([r].[IsActive] = 1) AND (([r.Employer].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%' OR [r.Contractor].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%') OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Records_Products] AS [rp]
        INNER JOIN [Product_Defendant] AS [rp.ProductDefendant] ON [rp].[DefendantProductID] = [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantProductID]
        INNER JOIN [Defendants] AS [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant] ON [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantID] = [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantID]
        WHERE ([rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%' AND ([rp].[IsActive] = 1)) AND ([r].[RecordID] = [rp].[RecordID])))
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[SourceCode]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
```

Here is the new sql that works better, just not sure how to convert it back to a lambda expression

```html
SELECT [t].[Id]
 ,[t].[StartDate]
 ,[t].[EndDate]
 ,[t].[WitnessName]
 ,[t].[SourceCode]
 ,[t].[JobsiteName]
 ,[t].[ShipName]
 ,[t].[EmployerCode]
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT [r].[RecordID] AS [Id]
  ,[r].[StartDate]
  ,[r].[EndDate]
  ,[r.Witness].[FullName] AS [WitnessName]
  ,CASE 
   WHEN [r].[SourceID] IS NOT NULL
    THEN [r.Source].[SourceCode]
   ELSE N'zzzzz'
   END AS [SourceCode]
  ,CASE 
   WHEN [r].[JobsiteID] IS NOT NULL
    THEN [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteName]
   ELSE N'zzzzz'
   END AS [JobsiteName]
  ,CASE 
   WHEN [r].[ShipID] IS NOT NULL
    THEN [r.Ship].[ShipName]
   ELSE N'zzzzz'
   END AS [ShipName]
  ,CASE 
   WHEN [r].[EmployerID] IS NOT NULL
    THEN [r.Employer].[DefendantCode]
   ELSE N'zzzzz'
   END AS [EmployerCode]
 FROM [Records] AS [r]
 LEFT JOIN [Ships] AS [r.Ship] ON [r].[ShipID] = [r.Ship].[ShipID]
 LEFT JOIN [Jobsites] AS [r.Jobsite] ON [r].[JobsiteID] = [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteID]
 LEFT JOIN [Sources] AS [r.Source] ON [r].[SourceID] = [r.Source].[SourceID]
 LEFT JOIN [Witnesses] AS [r.Witness] ON [r].[WitnessID] = [r.Witness].[WitnessID]
 LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Contractor] ON [r].[ContractorID] = [r.Contractor].[DefendantID]
 LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Employer] ON [r].[EmployerID] = [r.Employer].[DefendantID]
 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT [rp].[RecordID]
  FROM [Records_Products] AS [rp]
  INNER JOIN [Product_Defendant] AS [rp.ProductDefendant] ON [rp].[DefendantProductID] = [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantProductID]
  INNER JOIN [Defendants] AS [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant] ON [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantID] = [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantID]
  WHERE (
    [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%'
    AND ([rp].[IsActive] = 1)
    )
  ) AS RecordProduct ON [r].[RecordID] = RecordProduct.[RecordID]
 WHERE ([r].[IsActive] = 1)
  AND (
   (
    [r.Employer].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%'
    OR [r.Contractor].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%'
    )
   OR RecordProduct.RecordID IS NOT NULL --OR EXISTS ( --    SELECT 1 --    FROM [Records_Products] AS [rp] --    INNER JOIN [Product_Defendant] AS [rp.ProductDefendant] ON [rp].[DefendantProductID] = [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantProductID] --    INNER JOIN [Defendants] AS [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant] ON [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantID] = [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantID] --    WHERE ([rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + 'cert') + N'%'  -- AND ([rp].[IsActive] = 1)) AND ([r].[RecordID] = [rp].[RecordID]) -- )  )) AS [t]ORDER BY [t].[SourceCode]OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
   )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The linq expression you supplied and the SQL generated do not match. For one, the linq expression is performing an `Include` on the various related tables which would have included all of those entity columns in the top-level SELECT which are not present in your example SQL. I also don't see conditions in the Linq expression for the Take 500 & OrderBy, or IsActive assertion on Record.

To be able to help determine the source of any performance concern we need to see the complete Linq expression and the resulting SQL.

Looking at the basis of the Linq expression you provided:

```
records = records
    .Include(r => r.Employer)
    .Include(r => r.Contractor)
    .Include(r => r.RecordProducts)
    .ThenInclude(rp => rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant)
    .Where(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Employer.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(r.Contractor.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%") && rp.IsActive == true));
```

There are a few suggestions I can make:

1. There is no need for the `Functions.Like`. You should be able to achieve the same with `Contains`.
2. Avoid using `Include` and instead utilize `Select` to retrieve the columns from the resulting structure that you actually need. Populate these into ViewModels or consume them in the code. The less data you pull back, the better optimized the SQL can be for indexing, and the less data pulled across the wire. Consuming entities also leads to unexpected lazy-load scenarios as systems mature and someone forgets to `Include` a new relation.

.

```
records = records
    .Where(r => r.IsActive
        && (r.Employer.DefendantCode.Contains(input.DefendantCode)
          || r.Contractor.DefendantCode.Contains(input.DefendantCode)
          || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => rp.IsActive 
              && rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode.Contains(input.DefendantCode))
   .OrderBy(r => r.SourceCode)
   .Select(r => new RecordViewModel
   {
      // Populate the data you want here.
   }).Take(500).ToList();
```

This also adds the IsActive check, `OrderBy`, and `Take(500)` based on your sample SQL.

Comment: Hi Steve. I'm pretty much doing everything that you said, but my problem is on this line "rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode" when I have to go through the "ProductDefendant", where as before my performance issue I was going from "rp.Defendant" (directly to Defendant) so now that I'm going through another table my performance is much higher ~40 secs / query

Comment: So after looking at the generated SQL my coworker rewrote it and now I'd like to translate that back into a lambda expression. I just don't know how

Comment: If the introduction of that ProductDefendant table has been linked to the performance drop then I would suspect a possible indexing issue at the DB level. have you captured the executed SQL and ran them in SSMS (assuming SQL Server) with an execution plan? if RecordProduct had a Defendant originally, why was a ProductDefendant table introduced? Something like that would hint at a many-to-many join between product & defendant, but the model doesn't seem to match that.

Comment: One option for complex relationships is to create a view to bind a new entity to. You can structure the data returned in the view, then define a matching entity for the view output. This works well for cases where you want to summarise data, but not for editing. For editing you'd load applicable table-based entities by ID.